# Geo Locator Location permission

Tags: xamarin, permissions, geolocation

I am using GeoLocator for location. I have given permission in the manifest for:
1.Access_Coarse_Location
2.Access_Fine_Location
3.Internet

Still, it is not asking for permission. I have to give permission from Device App Setting. otherwise, the app will be crash.
Please give me the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From android 6 and onward you have to request the permission at the run-time.
You have added permissions in manifest, hence you can allow them in settings.
But as you haven't requested for them when the app starts or your activity launches, your app doesn't have the required permission and hence it's crashing.

You can follow this article to know how to request permission at run-time.

https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/